# OnTouchEvent not working on child views

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I have a Linear Layout that has a Button and a TextView on it. I have written a OnTouchEvent for the activity. The code works fine if I touch on the screen, but if I touch the button the code does not work. What is the possible solution for this?

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   int eventaction=event.getAction();


   switch(eventaction)
   {
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
      reg.setText("hey");


   break;
   }
   return true;

  }
```

Comment: Please paste the code of your activity.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The problem is the order of operations for how Android handles touch events.  Each touch event follows the pattern of (simplified example):

1. Activity.dispatchTouchEvent()
2. ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent()
3. View.dispatchTouchEvent()
4. View.onTouchEvent()
5. ViewGroup.onTouchEvent()
6. Activity.onTouchEvent()

**But events only follow the chain until they are consumed** (meaning somebody returns true from `onTouchEvent()` or a listener).  In the case where you just touch somewhere on the screen, nobody is interested in the event, so it flows all the way down to your code.  However, in the case of a button (or other clickable `View`) it consumes the touch event because it is interested in it, so the flow stops at Line 4.

If you want to monitor all touches that go into your Activity, you need to override `dispatchTouchEvent()` since that what always gets called first, `onTouchEvent()` for an Activity gets called last, and only if nobody else captured the event. Be careful to not consume events here, though, or the child views will never get them and your buttons won't be clickable.

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   int eventaction=event.getAction();

    switch(eventaction) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          reg.setText("hey");
          break;
      default:
          break;
    }

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Another option would be to put your touch handling code into a custom `ViewGroup` (like `LinearLayout`) and use its `onInterceptTouchEvent()` method to allow the parent view to steal away and handle touch events when necessary.  Be careful though, as this interaction is one that cannot be undone until a new touch event begins (once you steal one event, you steal them all).

HTH

Comment: can u provide some code which i can implement in my problem?? that would be helpful

Comment: Added.  Also, you might to edit the question to include both your question text AND the code sample, so that people looking at this in the future can benefit from the answer.

Comment: i used ur code  to switch between screens of my application. But the switching of the screens is completely random . It is not in a fixed order..

Comment: Make sure you don't still also have the `onTouchEvent()` code, this replaces that.  This sounds like a separate question, which would require a deeper examination of your code.  But it also sounds like you might need to read up a bit more on how to do custom touch handling, because it can be very tricky if you don't catch all the cases.  Here's a presentation I did recently that might help you understand the process better: http://www.andevcon.com/AndevCon_III/downloadpresentation.aspx?aid=Mastering_the_Android_Touch_System_pdf.zip&sid=6

Comment: action_move  is responding on a very small click also..I want that it should work when the user drags the screen

Comment: Then you need to focus on the section of the powerpoint that deals with slop checks.  The example code from the presentation may also be helpful: https://github.com/devunwired/custom-touch-examples

Comment: i tried your example but could not get how to implement it my code..can u add a little code in the code that u posted for me that works when user slides atleast half the screen..

Comment: Thanks a ton for your answer @Devunwired. Just one more question, can I ask you how did you know this? What I'm trying to get at is, if I wouldn't have found your answer here on Stackoverflow, what would have been the right way to get to the answer? Can this information be found from the docs somewhere? I tried but couldn't find it.

Comment: Most of this is documented in the descriptions of each individual method, but figuring out the order in which they call each other was mostly obtained from tracing the source code.

Comment: The order of touch callbacks was very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent answer! My problem was different where I didn't check for a specific type of action in `onTouchEvent` or break execution after `Action_Down` occurred. I just implemented part of your answer, the checking for an action and breaking execution appropriately. You are an absolute lifesaver, much thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

Let me add one more comment to this excellent post by @Devunwired.

If you've also set an onTouchListener on your View, then its onTouch() method will be called AFTER the dispatch methods, but BEFORE any onTouchEvent() method, i.e. in between no.3 and no.4 on @Devunwired's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the [descendantFocusability](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android%3adescendantFocusability) attribute of your layout to blocksDescendants

Answer (score 0):

`Activity::onTouchEvent` will be called only when non of the views in the Activity WIndow consumes/handles the event. If you touch the `Button`, the `Button` will consume the events, so the Activity won't be able to handle it.

Check out following articles for more about Android Touch Event handling pipeline.

http://pierrchen.blogspot.jp/2014/03/pipeline-of-android-touch-event-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

you can also try `onUserInteraction()`:

```
@Override 
public void onUserInteraction(){
     //your code here
     super.onUserInteraction();
}
```

works well for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
RecyclerView list_view = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
list_view.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.SimpleOnItemTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(@NonNull RecyclerView rv, @NonNull MotionEvent e) {
        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        Log.i("Hello", "World");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

use `public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` instead on `onTouchEvent()`