# Override bool in fragment using C# - Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, fragment

I have some problem with my codes. The override bool is not working in the fragment but when I try it on the activity. It works perfectly. The error says "No suitable method found to override". I don't know why the override bool is not working in the fragment.

[image: Here is the picture of the error]

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using SupportFragment = Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Support.V4.Widget;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Views.Animations;

namespace EFCAndroid
{
    public class Fragment_menu : SupportFragment
    {
        private float initialX;
        private ViewFlipper viewflipper;
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
            // return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.YourFragment, container, false);
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_menu, container, false);

            viewflipper = view.FindViewById<ViewFlipper>(Resource.Id.viewFlipper);

            viewflipper.SetInAnimation(Activity, Resource.Animation.fade_in);
            viewflipper.SetOutAnimation(Activity, Resource.Animation.fade_out);
            viewflipper.SetFlipInterval(5000);
            viewflipper.StartFlipping();

            return view;

        }

        public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent ontouch)
        {

            //switch (ontouch.Action)
            switch(ontouch.Action)
            {
                case MotionEventActions.Down:
                    initialX = ontouch.GetX();
                    break;
                case MotionEventActions.Up:
                    float finalX = ontouch.GetX();
                    if (initialX > finalX)
                    {
                        if (viewflipper.DisplayedChild == 1)
                            break;
                        //viewflipper.SetInAnimation(this, Resource.Animation.fade_in);
                        //viewflipper.SetInAnimation(this, Resource.Animation.fade_out);
                        viewflipper.ShowNext();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (viewflipper.DisplayedChild == 0)
                            break;
                        //viewflipper.SetInAnimation(this, Resource.Animation.fade_in);
                        //viewflipper.SetInAnimation(this, Resource.Animation.fade_out);
                        viewflipper.ShowPrevious();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Fragment doesn't have ontouchevent method

Comment: Hi. I try the example that your gave to me. But still not working. I put override inside the view.setontouchlistener. But still got the error says No suitable method found to override :3

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Comment: Still error when i write the (new View.IOnTouchListener()

There is no function called view.ontouchlistener() in c# :(

Comment: It is not `view.ontouchlistener()`, it is `view.SetOnTouchListener();`, note the package, it is `using Android.Views;`. [Here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Views.View.SetOnClickListener/p/Android.Views.View+IOnClickListener/) you can see the method in c#.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment doesn't have ontouchevent to be replaced. maybe you can use this link [How to handle Touch Events on a Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882251/how-to-handle-touch-events-on-a-fragment)

Comment: Hi. I try the example that your gave to me. But still not working. I put override inside the view.setontouchlistener. But still got the error says No suitable method found to override :3

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882251/how-to-handle-touch-events-on-a-fragment) is using java. After translate into c#, it should like this:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;

namespace FragmentTest
{
    public class Fragment1 : Fragment,View.IOnTouchListener
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout1, container, false);
            view.SetOnTouchListener(this);
            return view;

            
        }

        public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
        {
            if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Move){
                //do something 
                Log.Error("lv","MOVE++++++++++++++++++");
                }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

It works well.

Because, there is no `OnTouchEvent` method in Fragment, so we need implement it by ourselves. Or there is another way to achieve it by define an interface, and use `dispatchTouchEvent` method, it's more complex than above codes.