# onTouchEvent called from ViewGroup but onTouchListener of view isnt called

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, touch-event, gesturedetector, ontouch

So i have intercepted a touch event in a custom viewgroup. From here in the viewgroup's onTouchEvent I want the call the onTouchEvent of two of the child views at the same time.

Do i call both onTouchEvent and return only the second's value. I'm not sure why this is not working.

Shouldn't both views be getting the touchevents for the remainder of the gesture?

Inside one of the views i have a onTouchlistener whose onTouch event never gets called.

I want to send the touch events to both views for a while and once a condition is met only to the second view.

Comment: Some code would help.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001282/ontouchevent-not-working-on-child-views would help. I mean redefining of a method onInterceptTouchEvent (return true).