# I want to control a bitmap drawn using ontouch even i have used custom view extends surfaceview kindly help me

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, surfaceview

My Objective is to create a small game that has collision detection, player score, game loop, with a sound and replay option once a collision occurred.

So far I have managed to do a game loop with sound and using a custom view which extends a SurfaceView. I have created 2 bitmap images one of which runs from a fixed position(pig) the second one is an egg which is also a bitmap drawn using Canvas but it must be controlled by touch to avoid collisions but unfortunately I was not able to control it with touch

So Far my Code is as in the following link:

File 1:https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Z5pe2LVrTwSSH3KgJdGjUOZsFRTSr7y3BTttfyM8DKg/edit?usp=sharing

File 2: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cTv4xYEd0s42JRrCkZhGoAw6ZYWmdsoCTfHsG4u31Zo/edit?usp=sharing

Kindly please, help me with the touch thing and score if you can please and I'm new to both java and Android so kindly please be a bit elaborated please.

Comment: Where do you plug touch events to your SurfaceView?

Comment: It's in onTouch Event in file 1 and it's a bit moving but once moved it's making the app closed for some reason

Comment: Why it's not on your surfaceview, but in activity?

Comment: Should that be in GameView which extends surface view ??? i'm new to this android programming kindly please help

Comment: Try to place it in view, not in activity.  This answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001282/ontouchevent-not-working-on-child-views explains, why your activity.onTouchEvent can be never get called

Comment: Pleasee don't leave me alone this is one my important projects that decides my future kindly please help me with the coding

Comment: I answered to you. Try this method. If it will not working, let me know.