# Android: IllegalStateException relating to createCircularReveal

Tags: android

I'm getting a few crash reports for my app as follows:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.view.RenderNode.addAnimator (RenderNode.java:817)
  at android.view.RenderNodeAnimator.setTarget (RenderNodeAnimator.java:277)
  at android.view.RenderNodeAnimator.setTarget (RenderNodeAnimator.java:261)
  at android.animation.RevealAnimator.<init> (RevealAnimator.java:37)
  at android.view.ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal (ViewAnimationUtils.java:48)
  at com.example.myapp.MyConfigureActivity$8.run (MyConfigureActivity.java)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:211)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5335)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1016)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

I'm using the following functions within my `Activity` to make a view visible (with animation) or make the view gone (again, with animation):

```
public class MyConfigureActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static private Integer lastXup;
    static private Integer lastYup;

    void animateView(final View view, final int visibility) {
        final int duration = 250;

        view.post(new Runnable()
        {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                // get the center for the clipping circle
                int w = view.getWidth();
                int h = view.getHeight();
                int cx = (lastXup == null) ? w/2 : lastXup;
                int cy = (lastYup == null) ? h/2 : 0;

                // get the final radius for the clipping circle
                float r = Math.max(cx, w-cx);

                Animator anim;

                if (visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
                    // create the animator for this view (the start radius is zero)
                    anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, cx, cy, 0, r);
                    // make the view visible before starting the animation
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    // create the animation (the final radius is zero)
                    anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, cx, cy, r, 0);

                    // make the view GONE when the animation is finished
                    anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });

                }
                anim.setDuration(duration);
                anim.start();
            }
        });
    }

    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/11001443/4070848
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int eventaction = event.getAction();

        switch (eventaction) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                lastXup = (int) event.getRawX();
                lastYup = (int) event.getRawY();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

This seems to be working fine on the vast majority of devices, and I've never been able to reproduce a crash, but there is still a significant number of crashes being reported.  Any idea what might be the cause?

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem, have you found a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code of `RenderNode` you can find what could raise the exception in `addAnimator`:

```
if (mOwningView == null || mOwningView.mAttachInfo == null) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot start this animator on a detached view!");
}
```

So the error should appear when you starting the animation while app is closing and/or current activity is closing, or you view is removed for another reason - add checks for the cases (like setting some variable isAnimationAllowed=false in `onPause` and isAnimationAllowed=true in `onResume`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll try this and see whether the crash reports stop.