# Android: Scaling circles on a canvas with pinch

Tags: android, android-canvas, scaling

I currently can place and drag circles around on a canvas, but I'm having trouble understanding how to allow the user to scale circles with a pinch gesture.

The circles are drawn with 'canvas.drawCircle(x,y,radius,paint)'. My initial idea was to listen for the pinch gesture with a custom 'SimpleOnScaleGestureListener', and the multiply the radius of the selected circle by a scale factor. This has produced some pretty unpredictable results, with circles being scaled to tiny or epic proportions from a quick tap with two fingers.

Here's my custom listener:

```
private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

            @Override
            public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector){
                mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor()

                if (isCircleToolSelected) {
                    // Checks if gesture was made inside of an existing circle
                    // CircleDrawing is a private class that holds x,y,radius,paint values
                    CircleDrawing circle = getCircle(detector.getFocusX(), 
                                                     detector.getFocusY());

                    if (circle != null) {
                       touchedCircle.radius *= mScaleFactor;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
```

This detects the gesture and knows whether the pinch was within a circle on my canvas, but the scaling that is applied is just totally out of control and unusable.

I tried only scaling when the difference between the current and previous scale factors is beyond a certain threshold value, but that just made the scaling less predictable and more choppy.

If anyone has implemented something similar, I would love some direction.

Comment: Have you looked at this documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale

Comment: @ditkin I have looked at that documentation, but I admit that I'm confused as to the purpose of a lot of things in that version of onScale(). Should I be using getCurrentSpan() to find some number to add to my radius?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question in case someone else gets themselves convinced that you have to scale everything using a ScaleFactor. For basic scaling of a circle, you just need to find the difference between the current and previous value of getCurrentSpan().

This is the code that I wound up using:

```
//Used elsewhere to detect if we've touched an existing circle
CircleDrawing touchedCircle;

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

        private float lastSpan;
        private float lastRadius;

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

            //If the user has not already selected a circle
            if (null == touchedCircle) {

                // Check if we started scale gesture within existing circle
                touchedCircle = getCircle(detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());
            }

            //If a circle has been selected, save radius and span
            if (touchedCircle != null) {
                lastRadius = touchedCircle.radius;
                lastSpan = detector.getCurrentSpan();
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector){

            //If the user has the shapes tool selected - handled elsewhere
            if (isShapesSelected) {

                //If the user is touching a circle
                if (touchedCircle != null) {

                    //Value used to calculate new radius
                    float currentSpan = detector.getCurrentSpan();
                    float diameterDiff = currentSpan - lastSpan;

                    //Keep track of scaling direction for min and max sizes
                    boolean scalingUp = diameterDiff > 0;

                    //Only scale within radius sizes between 150 and 500
                    //Likely will change these values to relate to size of canvas
                    if ((!scalingUp && (lastRadius >= 150)) || (scalingUp && (lastRadius < 500))) {

                        //Calculate and set new radius
                        touchedCircle.radius += (diameterDiff)/2;

                        //Save radius and span for next frame
                        lastRadius = touchedCircle.radius;
                        lastSpan = detector.getCurrentSpan();
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, would you mind publishing/sending me the full code of the snippet above please?

Answer (score 0):

you have to get scale factor when you select circle

```
 private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

            if (isCircleToolSelected) {
                mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor()
                // Checks if gesture was made inside of an existing circle
                // CircleDrawing is a private class that holds x,y,radius,paintvalues
                CircleDrawing circle = getCircle(detector.getFocusX(), 
                                                 detector.getFocusY());

                if (circle != null) {
                   touchedCircle.radius *= mScaleFactor;
                }
            }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not fix the problem, but this is likely still a good change to make. 

I can limit when scaling happens according to where the user is making their gesture, but as soon as scaling is applied, it immediately shrinks to tiny or huge proportions.

Comment: ok good. i think you need to check where you initialize scale gesture. check its initialize or not

Comment: The ScaleGestureDetector is initialized in the onTouchEvent method.

Comment: ok check this link too maybe it will be helpful for you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001282/ontouchevent-not-working-on-child-views

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I figured it out and answered my own question. Using the span rather than scale factor was the trick.