# onTouchEvent MotionEvent.ACTION_UP registering to slowly

Tags: android, touch-event, motionevent

I have a 2D car hotlaping game, where pressing and holding the press of the left side of the screen turns left, same for the right side and when letting go of touching the screen the car goes straight. The problem is, when for example pressing the left side of the screen and after that quickly letting go of touching then touching the right side, the car still turns left. It seems like the onTouchEvent is too slow to register the MotionEvent.ACTION_UP/DOWN.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (event.getX() < screenX / 2) {
                    player.isGoingRight = true;
                    player.touch = true;
                }
                if (event.getX() > screenX / 2) {
                    player.isGoingLeft = true;
                    player.touch = true;
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                player.isGoingRight = false;
                player.isGoingLeft = false;
                player.touch = false;
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe they get batched and treated as a multi-touch event? See if you get `ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` / `.._UP` and their pointer ids.

Comment: Depending on your code structure the touch event might have gone through a lot of other methods taking time before your `onTouchEvent` is called. It might be more responsive if you implement you code in `dispatchTouchEvent` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11001443/2373819 as to why.

Comment: @Pawel it seems like they are more action ids than just up and down. I'm going through every possible action and noticed that with ACTION_POINTER_UP I get Problems, as with 2 fingers the coordinates of the finger that went up are registered. How do I get the coordinates of the finger that is still down?